# Android Studio emulator not showing flutter app

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

The emulator in android studio shows projects created in Java but not flutter.
The flutter doctor says no devices available.
I have tried the solutions below on three different pc and one mac but the issue is the same, sometimes it says please configure android sdk

I HAVE TRIED THE FOLLOWING SOLUTIONS:

**1.Changed the sdk from project structure[enter image description here][1]**

**2.Changed environment path variables**

**3.Changed system variables**

**4.File->Invalidate Caches and Restart**

Comment: Does the emulator show up in `adb devices`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new flutter project (use the default counter app no need to write code) in android studio. And then run it using the green arrow button on the top. If it doesn't work make a new emulator and run it.